# Where do I find the code for gd_calc.py?

Tags: python, gdal, grass-gis

I need to create a raster that is the average of a large set of other rasters (many thousands). I've learned from another question that the script gd_calc.py can do a limited version of this, limited to 26 input files. I'd like to modify the script to take an arbitrarily large number of input files, but I don't know where to find it on my system, being new to GRASS, Python, and just about everything else. So, can anyone tell me where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to answer your question i.e "where to find it on my system" when you don't say what system you are using or how you installed GDAL.

You can find the code [here](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py), though it won't be easy to modify to use an arbitrary number of rasters because of the way it's written. And you will be limited by the maximum length of your command line ([windows XP or later = 8191 characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473), linux/unix varies).

Comment: Thanks for writing gd_calculate. That is likely the answer to my real question, of how to average large numbers of rasters.